# Broadcast Transaction Error

Tags: transaction, send-transaction, swap

i getting  the below error, how fix it?

Operation (SWAP):

> USDC(EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v) ->
> SOL(So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112)

Liquidity Pool(Raydium): 58oQChx4yWmvKdwLLZzBi4ChoCc2fqCUWBkwMihLYQo2

Error:

> Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom
> program error: 0x2a

Logs:

> 0: "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]" 1: "Program
> 11111111111111111111111111111111 success" 2: "Program
> TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]" 3: "Program
> log: Instruction: InitializeAccount" 4: "Program
> TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3442 of 800000
> compute units" 5: "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
> success" 6: "Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8
> invoke [1]" 7: "Program log: calc_exact len:0" 8: "Program
> consumption: 782345 units remaining" 9: "Program consumption: 782239
> units remaining" 10: "Program log: Error: User token input does not
> match amm" 11: "Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8
> consumed 15275 of 796558 compute units" 12: "Program
> 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 failed: custom program
> error: 0x2a"

Comment: Hello! If you don't mind, could you provide more context about how or where you're sending the transaction that produces this error? Is it a script, the raydium frontend, or elsewhere?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a repost of https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8967/send-transaction-error-with-raydium