# Send Transaction Error with Raydium

Tags: transaction, send-transaction, swap

I getting  the below error, how fix it?

Operation (SWAP):

```
USDC(EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v) -> SOL(So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112)
```

Liquidity Pool(Raydium): 58oQChx4yWmvKdwLLZzBi4ChoCc2fqCUWBkwMihLYQo2

Error:

```
Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0x2a
```

Logs:

```
0: "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]" 
1: "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success" 
2: "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]" 
3: "Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount" 
4: "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3442 of 800000 compute units" 
5: "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success" 
6: "Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 invoke [1]" 
7: "Program log: calc_exact len:0" 
8: "Program consumption: 782345 units remaining" 
9: "Program consumption: 782239 units remaining" 
10: "Program log: Error: User token input does not match amm" 
11: "Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 consumed 15275 of 796558 compute units" 
12: "Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 failed: custom program error: 0x2a"
```

---

My scenario is SWAP from USDC (`EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v`) to SOL (`So1111111111111111111111111111111111112`), the swap is executed in nodejs script using `@raydium-io/raydium-sdk` (version: 1.1.0-beta. 39) and `@solana/web3.js` (version : 1.63.1).

Transaction data:

```
{
  "recentBlockhash": "2k2HT595PjzDAcjJ6eqmF64bsQnKGfrNVQyESQ2A7yZr",
  "feePayer": "8spngYvecZYQiHuruZaMtDazqwu35wF2AAJAxRQG9vuU",
  "nonceInfo": null,
  "instructions": [
    {
      "keys": [
        {
          "pubkey": "8spngYvecZYQiHuruZaMtDazqwu35wF2AAJAxRQG9vuU",
          "isSigner": true,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "GBa6dxiVfo7ZG56HFDhf1SRBLcBKuRSMgaWcKHDQf9jX",
          "isSigner": true,
          "isWritable": true
        }
      ],
      "programId": "11111111111111111111111111111111",
      "data": [
        0, 0, 0, 0, 240, 29, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 165, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6,
        221, 246, 225, 215, 101, 161, 147, 217, 203, 225, 70, 206, 235, 121,
        172, 28, 180, 133, 237, 95, 91, 55, 145, 58, 140, 245, 133, 126, 255, 0,
        169
      ]
    },
    {
      "keys": [
        {
          "pubkey": "GBa6dxiVfo7ZG56HFDhf1SRBLcBKuRSMgaWcKHDQf9jX",
          "isSigner": true,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": false
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "8spngYvecZYQiHuruZaMtDazqwu35wF2AAJAxRQG9vuU",
          "isSigner": true,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": false
        }
      ],
      "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
      "data": [1]
    },
    {
      "keys": [
        {
          "pubkey": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": false
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "EJQxe3iyrGdFteR3vU6ZDaiy4xvB2Aj9AQCFhLCjNtJH",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": false
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "FRgSPA6MLFaS1B1mZeh4NiLMwmNrE5T7b8MAjxrXfVQN",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "AtTCGn6VeYgbfxS3EmSf7kS9KHFZTXw7VKGxhtLmpgDd",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "8tyN7yuKiHBvdLqgv1HwKAsApe9Y6XW6Jg4Prh585CRQ",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "7BhGoVxPZrCofU2UE2bwKjmP77rGRDbtkygCzSNY9r3M",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": false
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "Fnm1bPXURtoS7aqytpigeCpzccWbu9QuhbNsDTcq9VLL",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "9tcPaHpysj5nWynBp2pLJzEZdj1ohcnBFGHLL7NK1yht",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "9MfhfM7UZpyVN56NLypjdCk5b7biiSVxNBCpaoZN63bv",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "6mWQMjT3qTpPgko9qTHU6a3fw3mkSXb1PVvr744nW7ap",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "S8JCjapwzADtvNLoVmN4kgoiVB5yTudDaByy6Z3pgt9",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "AhugP4JnFezxrDSLFmQzvS4kqg4t6Ve3SSK9PXCJSG2G",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "4MPrQFswSu5zgHqovRhRUEtLLZ6jNp4rsSwb17HvZ7G2",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": false
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "PFATeyRkDhqCa1sspMxr1ZyyFiPhQC77LQtXpYbvZQc",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "GBa6dxiVfo7ZG56HFDhf1SRBLcBKuRSMgaWcKHDQf9jX",
          "isSigner": true,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "8spngYvecZYQiHuruZaMtDazqwu35wF2AAJAxRQG9vuU",
          "isSigner": true,
          "isWritable": true
        }
      ],
      "programId": "675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8",
      "data": [11, 173, 4, 213, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 89, 78, 54, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    {
      "keys": [
        {
          "pubkey": "GBa6dxiVfo7ZG56HFDhf1SRBLcBKuRSMgaWcKHDQf9jX",
          "isSigner": true,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "Cnko8X8ZYUjMVUCzajkXs2hqMwRaqbXjD4ugLMHGNZtF",
          "isSigner": false,
          "isWritable": true
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "8spngYvecZYQiHuruZaMtDazqwu35wF2AAJAxRQG9vuU",
          "isSigner": true,
          "isWritable": true
        }
      ],
      "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
      "data": [9]
    }
  ],
  "signers": [
    "8spngYvecZYQiHuruZaMtDazqwu35wF2AAJAxRQG9vuU",
    "GBa6dxiVfo7ZG56HFDhf1SRBLcBKuRSMgaWcKHDQf9jX"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please also add the code you're using to build & send your transaction